Upper and lower bounds for $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}a^2b$
When dealing with 3-variable inequalities, often we meet expressions like $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}a^2b$ ($a,b,c>0$), which becomes a problem if we attempt to use the pqr method. The reason is that $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}a^2b$ cannot be expressed only using $\displaystyle abc,\;\sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}a,\;\sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}ab$. Therefore, I am trying to find some upper and lower bounds which can be written only using pqr for it.
My attempt For lower bounds, an obvious one is $\displaystyle 3abc$. However, I think this lower bound is not close enough to $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}a^2b$. Then I find one interesting inequality $$\sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}a^2b\sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}a\geq \bigg(\sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}ab\bigg)^2,$$ which is correct using the Cauchy inequality. Then the lower bound can be $\displaystyle \frac{\big(\sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}ab\big)^2}{\sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}a}$. I think this one is better than $3abc$ since there's always $\displaystyle \bigg(\sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}ab\bigg)^2\geq 3abc\sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}a$.
For upper bounds, the obvious one is $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}a^3$. Also, I think this is not close enough to $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}a^2b$. However, the Cauchy inequality tells me that $$\bigg(\sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}a^2b\bigg)^2\leq\sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}a^2b^2\sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}a^2,$$ so the upper bound can be $\displaystyle \sqrt{\sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}a^2b^2\sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}a^2}$. By the way, this one is better than $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}a^3$ since $$\bigg(\sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}a^3\bigg)^2-\sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}a^2b^2\sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}a^2=\sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}\bigg(a^3b^3-a^2b^2c^2\bigg)+\sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}\bigg(\frac{a^6+2a^3b^3-3a^4b^2}{2}\bigg)+\sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}\bigg(\frac{a^4b^2+b^6-2a^2b^4}{2}\bigg)\geq 0.$$ However, if we want to use this upper bound, we have to take the square, which increases our calculation.
Please help if you find some upper or lower bounds which is better than what I've found. Also, any techniques to deal with $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}a^2b$ are welcomed. Any help will be appreciated.

Does $\sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}a \sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}a^2 = \sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}a^3 + \sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}a^2 b + \sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}a^2 c $ help?

In terms of $p, q, r$ ($p = a + b + c, q = ab + bc + ca, r = abc$), your lower bound is
$$a^2b + b^2 c + c^2a \ge \frac{q^2}{p},$$
and your upper bound is
$$a^2b + b^2 c + c^2a \le \sqrt{(q^2 - 2pr)(p^2 - 2q)}.$$
Here is a lower bound better than yours due to Vo Quoc Ba Can:
$$a^2b + b^2 c + c^2a \ge \frac{q^2}{p} + \frac{4(p^2 - 3q)r}{p^2}.$$
Here is a upper bound which does not involve sqrt due to KaiRain:
$$a^2b + b^2 c + c^2a \le \frac{9261r^2 - 862rp^3 + 73p^6}{484p^3}.$$
(Note: Your upper bound is not better than this, and this is not better than yours.)

Denote $\cases{p=a+b+c\\q=ab+bc+ca\\r=abc}$ and $\cases{X=\sum_{\text{cyc}}a^2b\\Y=\sum_{\text{cyc}}ab^2}$. Thanks to WolframAlpha, from (1) and (2) we have:
$$\begin{align}
&(1)\implies pq = (a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca) = X+Y+3abc \implies \color{red}{ X+Y =pq-3r }\tag{3}\\
&(2) \implies \color{red}{XY = 9 r^2 + p^3r - 6 pqr + q^3}  \tag{4}
\end{align}$$
Solve the quadratic equation from $(3)(4)$, we can deduce that $X$ can only receive two values $z_1$ or $z_2$:
$$X=\color{red}{z_1:=\frac{1}{2}\left(p q - 3 r - \sqrt{p^2 q^2 - 4 q^3 - 4 p^3 r + 18 p q r - 27 r^2}\right)}$$
or
$$X=\color{red}{z_2:=\frac{1}{2}\left(p q - 3 r + \sqrt{p^2 q^2 - 4 q^3 - 4 p^3 r + 18 p q r - 27 r^2}\right)}$$
It's evident that $z_1 \le z_2$, as a consequence, the strictest bounds (in function of $p,q,r)$) for $X=\sum_{\text{cyc}}a^2b$ is
$$\color{red}{z_1 \le \sum_{\text{cyc}}a^2b \le z_2}$$
